# Selenium FindBy to find a header tag by it's text

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to use the FindBy to get the H5 element containing the text "ALLEN VERSION" in the below HTML:

```html
<div id="showAboutContent" class="modal fade in" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 550px;">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header" style="color: #96c4f3;background-color: #071c3f;">
<div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #D6E3F9; overflow-y: hidden; ">
<div class="modal-body" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: -20px; overflow-y: hidden;">
<img style="width:120px;height:120px; opacity:20" src="/ALEX/Logo/AboutBoxLogosvg.svg">
<h5>
<h5>
<h5>
<b> ALEX Version: 1.6.0 </b>
</h5>
<h5>
<b> ALLEN Version: 1.4.0 </b>
</h5>
<div style="background-color: #D6E3F9; padding: 10px; text-align: right; ">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I did not include the entire page's HTML, I didn't think it is necessary to include because I already found the frame that the H5 is contained within:

```
var aboutFrame = driver.FindElement(By.Id("showAboutContent"));
```

So since I already have that element found, I then found the h5 that I wanted within that frame by using it's tagname and index, as shown below:

```
var allenVersion = aboutFrame.FindElements(By.TagName("h5"))[3];
```

However, I would like to find the element using some type of "text contains" method instead. This is because there might be more h5's added to that window, so I dont want to find it by index like I have been doing, and I want it to be a "Contains" type of query, because the version number always changes. So I can just do a text contains "ALLEN Verson".

Answer (score 1):

There may be a couple of ways to skin this.

**Method 1** : Check all h5 elements

One would be to select all the H5 tags and then identify the one you are looking for.  It might look something like this.

```
var allenVersion;
var tags = aboutFrame.FindElements(By.TagName("h5"));
foreach (var tag in tags) {
  if (tag.Contains("ALLEN Version")) {
    allenVersion = tag;
    break;
  }
}
```

**Method 2** : XPath

You could also use an XPath selector to find your version element.  You can design your XPath selector around the document structure or around the text you are looking for. This might look something like this.

```
var allenSelector = By.XPath("//*/div[@class='modal-body'/h5[4]");
var allenVersion = aboutFrame.FindElement(allenSelector);
```

or

```
var allenSelector = By.XPath("//*/h5/b[contains(text(), 'ALLEN Version')]");
var allenVersion = aboutFrame.FindElement(allenSelector);
```

Comment: This worked, I used the XPath example with containstext. Can you edit that and include a containstext example utilizing CssSelector?

Comment: I haven't tried this using a css selector.  There is a contains() pseudo function that was never added to the official css spec.  You can use it in jQuery and maybe through the webdriver interface.  have to try it.